# Unable to implement Quicksort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have written an implementation of Quicksort in Python using the algorithm as taught by Sedgewick in his course. I am unable to sort it properly. What is wrong with the code?

```
def partition(a, lo, hi):
    i = lo
    j = hi
    v = a[lo]
    while(True):
        while(a[i] < v):
            i += 1
            if (i == hi): break

        while(a[j] > v):
            j -= 1
            if (j == lo): break

        if (i >= j): break

        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

    a[lo], a[j] = a[j], a[lo]
    return j

def sort(a, lo, hi):
    if (hi <= lo):
        return
    q = partition(a, lo, hi)
    sort(a, lo, q-1)
    sort(a, q+1, hi)
    assert isSorted(a, lo, hi)

def quick_sort(a):
    shuffle(a)
    sort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
    assert isSortedArray(a)
```

Comment: Moreover, you lacked luck in choosing the StackExchange community to ask, if nothing else. (How do you sort a single quicksort implementation?)

Answer (score 0):

You might find these reference implementations helpful while trying to understand your own.

---

**Returning a new list:**

```
def qsort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    head, *tail = array
    less = qsort([i for i in tail if i < head])
    more = qsort([i for i in tail if i >= head])
    return less + [head] + more
```

---

**Sorting a list in place:**

```
def quicksort(array):
    _quicksort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

def _quicksort(array, start, stop):
    if stop - start > 0:
        pivot, left, right = array[start], start, stop
        while left <= right:
            while array[left] < pivot:
                left += 1
            while array[right] > pivot:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
                left += 1
                right -= 1
        _quicksort(array, start, right)
        _quicksort(array, left, stop)
```

---

**Generating sorted items from an iterable:**

```
def qsort(sequence):
    iterator = iter(sequence)
    head = next(iterator)
    try:
        tail, more = chain(next(iterator), iterator), []
        yield from qsort(split(head, tail, more))
        yield head
        yield from qsort(more)
    except StopIteration:
        yield head

def chain(head, iterator):
    yield head
    yield from iterator

def split(head, tail, more):
    for item in tail:
        if item < head:
            yield item
        else:
            more.append(item)
```

Comment: Please link to where you found the reference implementations in your answer.

Comment: I wrote the reference implementations, but they can be found in at least one other answer here on StackOverflow, and they were originally posted to Rosetta Code after being dissatisfied with the other implementations present.